# Separe part of a mesh to create a single object

Tags: blender, mesh

I'm totally beginner in blender, I'm trying to move out part of a mesh, like the video here:

https://mega.nz/file/G48AiLDT#JCUAie3MobgVkAoA4xw1y1PuhZfx3Ad9A9rKqKyRbrs

but I can't select all the vertex. Is there a way to do it?

The aim is to export the mesh as a single .obj element.